# Slick2D and JOGL, both libraries needed?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, slick2d

I am a little confused regarding jar and lib management with the use of `OpenGL` in addition to `Slick2D`. I understand that `Slick2D` is essentially a more user friendly way of using `OpenGL`, or a wrapper if you will, but I am unsure on how to handle the libraries.

Do I need to include both the `OpenGL` and `Slick2D` jars and libs in my project, or just Slick?

Does it even matter?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on various things.

You can get a lot wrappers for different things, there is also a bunch for utility classes, for instance `Slick-Util`.

> Slick2D and JOGL, both libraries needed?

Well if you've linked `Slick2D` into your program then you don't need to link `JOGL`, because `Slick2D` is build upon `LWJGL` (Another OpenGL wrapper, if you didn't know). So you can for sure unlink and remove `JOGL` from the project.

**Though** if you use some class of any sort from the `JOGL` library then you of course can't remove it. If you don't know for sure, then the easiest way to find out is:

1. Unlink any library
2. Run you program
3. If the program crashes or comes up with any warnings or errors which it didn't do before, then link the library to the project again.

Usually if you simply unlink a jar from your project, your IDE would tell you that it's missing some classes, if some of the classes was from the library you unlinked.

If you use any native .dll files, which you probably do because of OpenGL, then you can remove the once which aren't for the OS which you're using. **Though** it's best to keep them, because then your program would still be cross-platform. When I create some OpenGL programs, I usually only have the Windows Natives, though when I export the program I always add the natives for Linux, Solaris and Mac.